# ClickOnce Version Already Exists Warning When Publishing

Tags: clickonce

I have published an app using ClickOnce for about a year with relatively few issues.

This week I am off site, but needed to make some changes to the app and the way the autoupdate works - so I am publishing to the IIS of my local machine rather than the normal distribution server for testing.  The wierd thing is that as of yesterday afternoon, I started receiving the warning

`Published version 2.1.3.18 already exists on the server, do you want to overwrite it`

But the version i am publishing is way beyond that (2.1.3.32 currently), so I shouldn't be receiving the warning at all.

Frankly, it's not hurting anything, I can choose yes and publish over it without any problem, but I would like to know what is happening.  Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**
2.1.3.18 is on the server, but I am publishing versions greater than that version, so I should not be warned.  The last version I published was 2.1.3.32.

The version number I am referring to above is the Publish Version from the Publish tab of VS2008, not the Assembly Version.

**MORE INFO**
I just opened my MYApp.Application file with MageUI and it says the version is 2.1.3.18.  I deleted the file, recompiled and published.  New file has the exact same version.  Yet when I look under my VS Publish tag, it says Deployment Version is 2.1.3.33.

Where is VS pulling the 2.1.3.18 number from when building my manifest??

Comment: Just to throw in another observation of this issue:  In my experience, the version number in the warning message kept incrementing with every failed attempt, e.g. `1.0.0.17`, then `1.0.0.18`, and so on.  It must have been auto-incrementing each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same problem today, Just do a "Clean" on the project and then publish again (right click over project icon in solution explorer then *Clean*). This worked for me.

Comment: In fact is the first use that I find to the Clean option xD.

Comment: i spend 2 hours trying to figure out this, and you saved me. Thanks

Comment: Still applicable in 2022.  Take my internet credits.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the project's csproj.user file. I believe that the publish version should be there.

Comment: To add to the above, alternatively, this can be set from Project properties > publish menu.

Answer (score 1):

VS is warning you that version you are try to deploy is the same as the production.

My experience with clients and click-once deployments:
I think it's looking at the last click-once package build version which originates from the click-once page, not the project file version.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is pulling the "Publish Version" from the publish tab from the project's properties.

I get this warning too, but I generally just publish twice to get around it.

In additon you may want to check the "Automatically increment revision with each publish"

Comment: No. The publish version was 2.1.3.32, but the warning was for 2.1.3.18

Answer (score 1):

its quite so late for replying here but updating this for upcoming people search for the same, i got the same thing happening today with my running app all in sudden, on my work around i deleted BIN & OBJ folders and recreate them and all went fine.

Hope it help.

Aquariens

Comment: For people who didn't succeed with Clean command as suggested in the accepted answer, manually deleting bin and obj folders worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are updating the ClickOnce publish version, then you shouldn't get the question.

I have been doing quite a lot of publishing but never seen this *when it was not supposed to be there*.

I have an idea though, sorry but I'm not in a position to verify it now:

**Is your ClickOnce *Update* location set to something different that the *Publish* location?**

The Publish location is on the publish page, and the update location is under the *Updates* button. You probably should blank the update location out if you have it set.

Comment: Update location was not being used.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the csproj file being locked. I restarted the computer and it worked

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to click "Show all" on the Publish view then mash "Next" on the Publish modal until completion, all the while changing absolutely nothing.  *Then* it published successfully.

Things that did *not* work for me:

- Running "Clean solution
- Exiting and restarting Visual Studio
- Rebooting the machine

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
I had a class library in my solution marked (erroneously) as 'Console app'. I marked it back to class library and my Clickonce publish worked again.