# Update VSTO Word Addin without VSTO auto-update (no rights for installation for users)

Tags: installation, ms-word, windows-installer, vsto, clickonce

I want to update a VSTO addin for word I create without let VSTO automatic update launch. In fact, my end-users have not enough rights for installing.

I only want to update it, not install because first install will be done with vsto installation from VS publish folder with administrator rights.

To update, I copy

```
MyWordAddIn.dll  
MyWordAddin.dll.manifest
```

from publish folder to appData folder where my addin is installed.

When I launch my word document which is linked with my VSTO file. I have an error

[image]

Sorry for french, It said that there's already another version which is installed.

But when I launch it the second, third... time,  I have no error.

Comment: Does this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977236/clickonce-version-already-exists-warning-when-publishing ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not because it's not the same problem. He has a problem with version, I have a problem while updating without vsto clickonce install.

Comment: Do you use MSI or click once?

Comment: I use Visual Studio publish tool generating an exe file

Comment: All other generation ways are accepted if they work !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you did not disable ClickOnce from automatically installing updates on application startup.  That would explain why your application is detecting that there is a new version in the publish folder and attempting to install the update.  Then, the error is occurring because you already manually updated the DLL in the appData folder, so when it see's that publish folder contains a DLL with the same version number, it gives the error stating that it's already installed.

You can disable the autoupdate by going into your startup project's settings in VS, clicking the publish tab, and then press the update button and set it to never check for updates.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, ClickOnce installations themselves do not require administrative privileges. The prerequisites may, but the installation of the actual ClickOnce app does not. That's why it gets installed under the user profile. So once the user has the prerequisites installed, you can use the automatic updates, unless in your case the user can't even write to his own profile folders.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just run the following command from the command prompt:

```
rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
```

You wouldn't need to change any update settings. Any newer versions would update from the specified location when found during the specified update interval.