Windows Form Application w/ OneClick Deployment Version Keeps reverting to 1.0.0.0
We are trying to publish our windows form application. It has been approximately 2 years since any changes were make and the development environment might have changed.
We are developing on DEV_PC and trying to deploy to PROD_PC. PROD_PC hosts a test application and production application in the folders C:\APP\Test & C:\APP\Prod.
On our development machine we have Visual Studio 2017. There are 9 projects under our solution. Our main project is main.Win. On our production machine our latest test version is Main.Win.Test_2_4_0_9. Whenever we go to publish settings under Main.Win we made the version 2.4.0.10. Whenever we click publish to reverts to 1.0.0.0. If we close and re-open visual studio the version saved on the publish settings revert back to 1.0.0.0
We have manually tried to change the project versions in the Main.Win.Test.exe.manifest under application files and Main.Win.Test.application under publish to the new versions, but we get the error that the hash value doesn't match.
We've published successfully to version 1.0.0.0 and then you can see it auto-increment to 1.0.0.1, but when you click publish again it says "Published version 1.0.0.0 already exists on the server. Do you want to overwrite it?". If you close the application and reopen it 1.0.0.1 reverts back to 1.0.0.0.

Maybe version control has the 1.0.0.0 copy and get reloaded on Get Latest?

Try to do a "Clean" to the project and then publish again (right click over project icon in solution explorer then Clean). Refer to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4218398
